# Can a hybrid install be converted to "internal"?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nook-hd

I have a hybrid (root on SD) install of CM on my Nook HD+.  I've decided I'd rather have it installed on the internal flash rather than on the microSD card.  Can I convert this installation or do I need to just follow the install instructions again for a non-hybrid install and start over?